# Swift - Issue with navigating to root controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue

I have a story board with following structure

```
NavigationController -> HomeViewController -> StoryBoardSegue (Id: SignUpViewController) -> SignUpViewController -> StoryBoardSegue (Id: SignupStep1ViewController) -> SignUpStep1ViewController -> StoryBoardSegue (Id: SignUpStep2ViewController) -> SignUpStep2ViewController
```

Above structure are for the user who has not logged in, I discontinued the segue chain at this point because, I want a totally different navigation structure as soon as the user logs in, for now the structure is

```
Navigation Controller -> MainMenuViewController
```

In each of the screen, I am redirecting user to new ViewController using the following method

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController", sender: self)
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUpViewController", sender: self)
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignupStep1ViewController", sender: self)
performSegue(withIdentifier: "SignUpStep2ViewController", sender: self)
```

As soon as the user reaches the last point of segue chain which is `SignUpStep2ViewController` and because no segue exist at this point, I am redirecting the user to another ViewController using the following code.

```
let mainMenuViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainMenuViewController")
present(mainMenuViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So far so good, now in MainMenuViewController when user clicks on logout, I want to take user to HomeViewController

I cannot use `performSegue` because no segue exist between MainMenuViewController and HomeViewController, I tried the following code

```
let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController")
self.present(homeViewController!, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

The issue is, for some reason, navigation menu does not show up in SignUpViewController if I use the code, from MainMenuController, how do I go back to HomeViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using unwindSegue, for the reference, in the HomeViewController, I added the following code

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

And In storyboard, drag + control from MainMenuViewController to Exit and select the method created previously

Then run the following code

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToHomeViewController", sender: self)
```

And this works perfectly, thanks to the following article which helped me understand the issue

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/12/18/working-with-unwind-segues-programmatically-in-swift/
http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/04/work-with-unwind-segue-in-swift-language-ios-8/